# i get an error in pygame when using vector2

Tags: python, pygame

I get an

> unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'pygame.math.Vector2' when

running the below code :

```
import pygame
from settings import *
vec = pygame.math.Vector2

class Player:
    def __init__(self, app, pos):
        self.app = app
        self.grid_pos = pos
        self.pix_pos = self.get_pix_pos()
        self.direction = vec(1,0)
        
    def update(self):
        self.pix_pos += self.direction

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(self.app.screen, PLAYER_COLOUR, self.pix_pos,
        self.app.cell_width//2-2)
    def move(self, direction):
        self.direction = direction
    def get_pix_pos (self):
        vec((self.grid_pos.x*self.app.cell_width)+TOP_BOTTOM_BUFFER//2+self.app.cell_width//2, (self.grid_pos.y*self.app.cell_height)+TOP_BOTTOM_BUFFER//2+self.app.cell_height//2)
```

the error is in line 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return` statement is missing in the method `Player.get_pix_pos`:

```py
class Player:
    # [...]

    def get_pix_pos (self):
        return vec((self.grid_pos.x*self.app.cell_width)+TOP_BOTTOM_BUFFER//2+self.app.cell_width//2, (self.grid_pos.y*self.app.cell_height)+TOP_BOTTOM_BUFFER//2+self.app.cell_height//2)
```